# reading compressed data gives different results

Tags: python, numpy

I am using genfromtxt in order to read data.

genfromtxt must work also for .gz files but it seems it doesn't.

Using simple data ( not .gz files )

```
f = open('file', 'r')
con = np.genfromtxt(f,dtype=str)

print con
print type(con)
```

file contents is:

```
 @HWI
    ABCDE
    +
    @HWI7
    EFSA
    +
    ???=AF
    GTEY@JF
    GVTAWM
```

and output of above code is:

```
['@HWI' 'ABCDE' '+' '@HWI7' 'EFSA' '+' '???=AF' 'GTEY@JF' 'GVTAWM']
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

If , I simply use the same code with the aboce file compressed as .gz file , the output is:

```
[ "\x1f\x8b\x08\x08\x1b4\x8eW\x00\x03file\x00Sp\xf0\x08\xf7\xe4R\x00\x02G'g\x17W0K\x1bL\x82$\xcc\xc1,W\xb7`G$"
 '{{{[G70\xd3=\xc45\xd2\xc1' '\xca\x0e' 'q' '\xf7\x05' '\x06\x07\xc2P']
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

And the problem is that I want to perform some calculations later and I can't like this.

I tried also ( for the .gz version ) :

```
with gzip.open(file, 'r') as f:
    con = np.array([f.read()])

print con
print type(con)
```

which gives :

```
[ ' @HWI\n    ABCDE\n    +\n    @HWI7\n    EFSA\n    +\n    ???=AF\n    GTEY@JF\n    GVTAWM']
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

which is closer to the initial but still doesn't work ( can't move on with calculations )

How can I accomplish the same result?

Comment: Why don't you use `genfromtxt` with the file object from `gzip.open()`?

Comment: have you tried `gzip.open("file","rt")`? By defualt `gzip.open` opens as binary

Comment: @MutationalMeltdown:I just tried it.Still the same

Comment: @resi:Yes!That;s it!Thanks!Make it an answer please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use `genfromtxt` with the file object from `gzip.open()`?

```
with gzip.open('file.gz') as f:
    print(numpy.genfromtxt(f, dtype=str))
```

**EDIT**

`numpy` uses predefined file openers for `.gz` and `.bz2` files. You can check the configuration like:

```
import numpy.lib._datasource as DS
DS._file_openers._load()
print(DS._file_openers._file_openers)
```

On my machine this shows handlers for bz2 and gz files:

```
{'.bz2': <type 'bz2.BZ2File'>, None: <built-in function open>, '.gz': <function open at 0x7efca562a6e0>}
```

Since the handler for gz files is actually `gzip.open`, it seems strange that numpy doesn't use it on your machine.

Comment: Even if this is an easy workaround it leaves you in charge to handle file name extensions/file types. `numpy.genfromtxt` is supposed to work as @rectummelancolique pointed out and would do that for you transparently.

Comment: I've edit my answer to point out numpy file openers. Did you maybe mess with your PYTHONPATH or sys.path?

Comment: :No, check my comment on rectummelancolique answer.The `f = open('file', 'r')` was the problem

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation:

```
genfromtxt(fname, dtype=<class 'float'>, comments='#', delimiter=None, skip_header=0, skip_footer=0, converters=None, missing_values=None, filling_values=None, usecols=None, names=None, excludelist=None, deletechars=None, replace_space='_', autostrip=False, case_sensitive=True, defaultfmt='f%i', unpack=None, usemask=False, loose=True, invalid_raise=True, max_rows=None)
    Load data from a text file, with missing values handled as specified.

    Each line past the first `skip_header` lines is split at the `delimiter`
    character, and characters following the `comments` character are discarded.

    Parameters
    ----------
    fname : file or str
        File, filename, or generator to read.  If the filename extension is
        `.gz` or `.bz2`, the file is first decompressed. Note that
        generators must return byte strings in Python 3k.
```

For the gzip version, you should try passing directly the filename (with `.gz` extension for compressed files.

Test data:

```
$> cat ./test.txt
 @HWI
     ABCDE
         +
             @HWI7
                 EFSA
                     +
                         ???=AF
                             GTEY@JF
                                 GVTAWM

$> gzip --stdout ./test.txt > ./test.txt.gz
```

Then in python:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.genfromtxt('./test.txt', dtype=str)
array(['@HWI', 'ABCDE', '+', '@HWI7', 'EFSA', '+', '???=AF', 'GTEY@JF',
       'GVTAWM'],
      dtype='<U7')
>>> np.genfromtxt('./test.txt.gz', dtype=str)
array(['@HWI', 'ABCDE', '+', '@HWI7', 'EFSA', '+', '???=AF', 'GTEY@JF',
       'GVTAWM'],
      dtype='<U7')
```

Comment: I just tried it here and it works for me, I will edit my answer to show how.

Comment: Hmm..I just found why it didn't work for me.I must delete this line `f = open('file', 'r')` and then it works as you say! ( I selected the answer,thats why I am upvoting you, thanks!)If you want update your answer according deletng the line.